# Execute hard task in Background Thread, return result in Main Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-asynctask

I spent some time to find a developer friendly solution (without adding dependencies to the project) of how to perform some hard task in background thread and after the task is completed return result to main thread. I found "AsyncTask" which allows to do that. But to use it you need to write boilerplate code for each task you need to run in Background. I am iOS developer who decided to try Android-related developing. So in Swift you can simply use the next code to make this task:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
      //Do some hard task in background
   DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
      //Return to main
   })
})
```

This looks pretty simple. But in Kotlin I didn't find such simple solution and decided to create it.

Here is what I made:

I created Generic class

```
import android.os.AsyncTask

class BaseAsyncTask<M>: AsyncTask<()->M, Int, M>() {

    var completion: ((M)->Unit)? = null

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: (() -> M)?): M? {
        for (p in params) {
            return p?.invoke()
        }
        return  null
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: M) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

        completion?.invoke(result)
    }
}
```

And Manager

```
class AsyncManager {

    companion object {

        fun <M>execute(inBackground: ()->M, inMain: (M)->Unit): BaseAsyncTask<M> {
            val task = BaseAsyncTask<M>()
            task.completion = inMain
            task.execute(inBackground)

            return task
        }

        fun <M>execute(inBackground: ()->M): BaseAsyncTask<M> {
            val task = BaseAsyncTask<M>()
            task.execute(inBackground)

            return task
        }
    }

}
```

Now I use it like this:

```
AsyncManager.execute({
   //Do some hard task in background
}, {
  //Return to main
})
```

Looks developer friendly.

```
Log.e("MAIN", "MAIN THREAD SHOULD NOT BE BLOCKED")

AsyncManager.execute({
    Log.e("TASK", "Started background task")
    val retval = "The value from background"
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    Log.e("TASK", "Finished background task with result: " + retval)
    retval
}, {
    Log.e("TASK", "Started task in Main thread with result from Background: " + it)
})

Log.e("MAIN", "MAIN THREAD SHOULD NOT BE BLOCKED - 1")
```

And the log:

> 2019-03-27 17:11:00.719 17082-17082/com.test.testapp E/MAIN: MAIN
>   THREAD SHOULD NOT BE BLOCKED
>
> 2019-03-27 17:11:00.722 17082-17082/com.test.testapp E/MAIN: MAIN
>   THREAD SHOULD NOT BE BLOCKED - 1
>
> 2019-03-27 17:11:00.722 17082-17124/com.test.testapp E/TASK: Started
>   background task
>
> 2019-03-27 17:11:05.737 17082-17124/com.test.testapp E/TASK: Finished
>   background task with result: The value from background
>
> 2019-03-27 17:11:05.738 17082-17082/com.test.testapp E/TASK: Started
>   task in Main thread with result from Background: The value from
>   background

So the question is what professional Android developers think about this solution. What problem can I get in case I'll use it. And maybe there is some reason not to use this solution.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Kotlin, the correct way to do this is via [Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html), which would allow you to write code such as:

```
// Launch a coroutine that by default goes to the main thread
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    // Switch to a background (IO) thread
    val retval = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Log.e("TASK", "Started background task")
        val retval = "The value from background"
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        Log.e("TASK", "Finished background task with result: " + retval)
        retval
    }
    // Now you're back the main thread
    Log.e("TASK", "Started task in Main thread with result from Background: " + retval)
}
```

Note that Kotlin coroutines operate under [structured concurrency](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952), so you'd generally want to avoid using `GlobalScope` and instead scope your coroutine to be tied to your Activity / Fragment lifecycle. This generally needs to be done yourself right now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for the solution without adding dependencies to the project.

Comment: @Dmitry - I think you need to get over that mental model. Writing a much worse version of something that already exists 100x better and better tested is never a sustainable approach.

Comment: Thank you. I'll think about this.

Comment: As same as mentioned in answer, Kotlin coroutines can be defined by the scope which helps to manage when coroutines should run.. One of the most useful scope is ViewModelScope that is defined for each ViewModel in your app. for more info https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecycle-aware

Comment: How do I do this in Compose

Answer (score 4):

[ianhanniballake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381044/2550406) is correct, but is perhaps a bit incomplete, so I figured I'd provide a full generic example.

*build.gradle(:app)*:

```
dependencies { // this line is probably already present
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3"
}
```

> A global CoroutineScope is not bound to any job.
>   GlobalScope is used
>   to launch top-level coroutines which are operating on the whole
>   application lifetime and are not cancelled prematurely. Application
>   code usually should use an application-defined CoroutineScope.
>   Using
>   async or launch on the instance of GlobalScope is **highly discouraged**.
>   <sub>taken from [here](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/handling-background-tasks-with-kotlin-coroutines-in-android-a674bab7a951)</sub>

So you want to use any class with a lifecycle as `CoroutineScope`, so that when it dies, it takes the running background tasks with it to the grave. Often, people recommend to use an activity for this. However, there is a [case to be made](https://proandroiddev.com/why-your-class-probably-shouldnt-implement-coroutinescope-eb34f722e510) that you don't want any external class to use your activity as their `CoroutineScope`, so you can use a protected field instead:

```
protected val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Main)
```

At the time of writing, I do not know why we have to create a `Job()` here. What I do know is that the `+` operator is overloaded to merge these two context into one. For the Dispatcher part, you can choose a reasonable one. The options include

- `Dispatchers.Main` for the UI thread
- `Dispatchers.Default` for a pool of background threads
- `Dispatchers.IO` for blocking operations that are I/O intensive
- `Dispatchers.Unconfined` for when you really know what you are doing. [This article](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/handling-background-tasks-with-kotlin-coroutines-in-android-a674bab7a951) discourages its use "normally".

Now with all this out of the way, the code becomes surprisingly simple:

```
import kotlin.coroutines.*
// ...
myButton.setOnClickListener() { v: View? ->
                myButton.setColorToYellow() // some UI thread work
                scope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    val result = longComputation() // some background work

                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        // some UI thread work for when the background work is done
                        root.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_home).text = "Result: $result"
                    }
                }
                myButton.setColorToRed() // more UI thread work. this is done instantly
       }
```

Of course, this can be done anywhere - I'm just using a button and an `onClickListener` to give an example with a possible use case.